# Struggling to refactor this using Ramda.js, here is how far I got

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm learning Ramda.js. The function I'm trying to refactor using Ramda is below. It calls a function `firestore` database method to get some data. But firestore returns data inside a `snapshot` method and we need to call `.data()`. Depending on the result, I want to construct different response.

**Would love to here your thought process**

```
const queryForUsersQuizResults = async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const snapshot = await firestore
      .collection("quizResults")
      .doc(request.user.uid)
      .collection("courses_chapters")
      .doc(request.params.courseId + "_" + request.params.chapterId)
      .get();

    let data = snapshot.data();
    if (!data) {
      data = {
        message: "result not found for this user for this course and chapter"
      };
    }

    return response.send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    return response.status(500).send(error);
  }
}
```

...and here is what I have been able to refactor, would love to see better/other ways of doing this (I'm not sure if this even works). I'm struggling with the `sendResult` method.

```
//get user id
export const getUserId = pathOr('', ['user', 'uid']);

// get chapter id
export const getChapterId = concat(pathOr('', ['params', 'courseId']), '_', pathOr('', ['params', 'chapterId']));

//queryQuizResult
export const query = curry(async (firestore, request) => {
  return tryCatch(() =>
    firestore
    .collection("quizResults")
    .doc(getUserId(request))
    .collection("courses_chapters")
    .doc(getChapterId(request))
    .get(), F)();
});

//Receives "response" object and calls response.status with the value passed to the new status function
export const status = invoker(1, "status");

//Receives "response" object and calls response.send witht he value passed to the new send function
export const send = invoker(1, "send");

//Create {"message",Your_Error} object
export const constructError = objOf('message');

//Returns JSON from Firestore's snapshot object
export const getDataFromSnapshot = (snapshot) => snapshot.data();

//Actual error message
const QUIZ_RESULTS_NOT_FOUND = "Quiz results not found for this user for this course and chapter";

//Returns error message
export const quizResultsNotFoundError = constructError(QUIZ_RESULTS_NOT_FOUND);

//Receives "response" object and calls response.status and then respose.send
export const sendError = pipe(
  status(401),
  send(quizResultsNotFoundError)
);
//Sends valid result  //IS there any better way of doing this?
export const sendResult = (snapshot, response) => {
  const data = getDataFromSnapshot(snapshot);
  response.send(data); //Especially this, I wanted to use the "send" method and pipe things
}

//Main Method
export const  queryForUsersQuizResults = async (firestore, request, response) => {
 const snapshot = await query(firestore, request);
 snapshot ? sendResult(snapshot, response) :sendError(response);
}
```

Comment: What was so very very wrong with the first version? I mean, I'd move the database check into a separate function but you seem to be adding a lot of complexity for very little gain.

Comment: I have many similar functions in my project so I'm refactoring them in  FP style so I can re-use. Most of my remaining functions will be just few lines of code I think.

Comment: I use Ramda all the time, but you aren't doing any data processing here you're just funneling stuff from the db to the front end. Which is fine, but it's simple and should be kept simple. If you want to factor out common stuff just make a HOF with the common logic that returns a handler. Or make a decorator. etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the moving parts I see. It's just one of the many possible ways to write the program. We'll start with a generic helper to [get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) `data` from a firestore request -

```js
const getData = doc =>
  doc.exists
    ? doc .data ()
    : Promise .reject (Error ("not found"))
```

We can now write a `queryForUsersQuizResults` but we are careful to keep it untangled from the route handler `request` and `response` -

```js
const queryForUsersQuizResults = (uid, docid) =>
  firestore
    .collection ("quizResults")
    .doc (uid)
    .collection ("courses_chapters")
    .doc (docid)
    .get ()
    .then (getData) // <- getData
```

Now we write `myRoute` to hand off `request` parameters to `queryForUsersQuizResults` and return a `response -

```js
const myRoute = (req, res) =>
  queryForUsersQuizResults
    ( req.user.uid
    , req.params.courseId + "_" + req.params.chapterId
    )
    .then
      ( handleSuccess (res)
      , handleError (404) (res)
      )
```

This depends on generic handlers `handleSuccess` and `handleError` that can be chained onto any promise -

```js
const handleSuccess = res => data =>
  res .send (data)

const handleError = code => res => err =>
  res .status (code) .send (err.message)
```

**demo**

Here's a working demo to show the concepts in action.
Since we don't have database, `firestore` or `express` available in stacksnippets, we have to mock them -

```js
const DB =
  { 1: "ant"
  , 2: "bear"
  , 3: "cuttlefish"
  }

const fakeFirestore = id =>
  new Promise
    ( r =>
        DB[id] === undefined
          ? r ({ exists: false })
          : r ({ exists: true, data: () => DB[id] })
    )

const fakeResponse = (status = 200) =>
  ({ send: data =>
       console .log ("=>", status, data)
   , status: n =>
       fakeResponse (n)
  })
```

We will test a query to each database record and a non-existing record -

```js
myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 1 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  )

myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 2 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  )

myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 3 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  )

myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 4 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  )
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const getData = doc =>
  doc.exists
    ? doc .data ()
    : Promise .reject (Error ("not found"))

const handleSuccess = res => data =>
  res .send (data)

const handleError = code => res => err =>
  res .status (code) .send (err.message)

const fakeResponse = (status = 200) =>
  ({ send: data =>
       console .log ("=>", status, data)
   , status: n =>
       fakeResponse (n)
  })
  
const fakeFirestore = id =>
  new Promise
    ( r =>
        DB[id] === undefined
          ? r ({ exists: false })
          : r ({ exists: true, data: () => DB[id] })
    )

const queryForUsersQuizResults = (id = 0) =>
  fakeFirestore (id)
    .then(getData)

const myRoute = (req, res) =>
  queryForUsersQuizResults (req.params.uid)
    .then
      ( handleSuccess (res)
      , handleError (404) (res)
      )

const DB =
  { 1: "ant"
  , 2: "bear"
  , 3: "cuttlefish"
  }

myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 1 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  ) // => 200 ant

myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 2 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  ) // => 200 bear

myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 3 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  ) // => 200 cuttlefish

myRoute
  ( { params: { uid: 4 } }
  , fakeResponse ()
  ) // => 404 not found
```

```
=> 200 ant
=> 200 bear
=> 200 cuttlefish
=> 404 not found
```

Comment: notice we didn't have to touch `async`/`await` too - save the heavy machinery for the hardest work

Answer (score 2):

I also think that what you have already is fine, if you really wanted to use composition, it could be something like this:

```
export const sendResult = (snapshot, response) =>
  pipe(getDataFromSnapshot, flip(send)(response))
    (snapshot);
```

You need to use `flip` as you don't have (at the time of the pipe definition) the result of `getDataFromSnapshot(snapshot)` yet, but you already have the object holding the implementation of your `send` method.